# vscode's openTextDocument closes tabs and window

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

In a unit test I have this:

```js
it("foo", async () => {
  let content = "";
  let document = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument({
    language: "text",
    content: content
  });
  let textEditor = await vscode.window.showTextDocument({ preview: false });
  //manipulate document ...
});
```

When I set a breakpoint in there - and I **step over** `showTextDocument` - the test vscode window's tabs are closed, and then vscode itself closes.

When I **step in**, it doesn't close anything, and goes to the next line (I've set up my `launch.json` to step over vscode's internals).

If I set a breakpoint **after** that line, it doesn't close anything.

What is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: I don't know why this happens but I have found that using `.then` instead of an `await` statement solved that issue.

Comment: @Charles Yes I found that too ... Weird! My syntax looks correct. Thanks for confirming that it's not just me.